# How to write the REBO force field

Tags: molecular-dynamics, software-recommendations, lammps, forcefields, software-input-file-request

I want to use the  [REBO-CHO](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-8984/16/41/008) force field to study graphene oxide using lammps. But I don't know how to create the input file with the parameters by reading the article or if there is a tutorial or software that does it.

Or if you already have the file and share it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the CHO extension of the REBO force field (which was further updated in a [later publication](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.84.075460)) also introduces some changes in formalism, which in turn are not implemented in LAMMPS. So it cannot be used natively.

The COMB3 force field is essentially a further extension of the REBO concept (sharing some authors). This is [implemented](https://docs.lammps.org/pair_comb.html) in LAMMPS, and has parameters for C/H/O. Of course, you'll have to search the literature or do your own checks to verify its applicability to your problem of interest.